# How do I add values to an array without them resetting to 0 outside the for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, random-seed

Im trying to write code that adds 3 items to an array, and later looks for any pairs. However, when the for loop ends, the array just resets to {0,0,0}. How do I "save" the array values so they dont reset after exiting the loop?

```
    srand(seed);
    const int RANDOMS_NEEDED = 3;
    int rando = 0;
    int rando_max = 10;
    int slotsOutput[3] = {};
    cout << "\t Generating random numbers from 0 to " << rando_max << endl << "\t";

    for (int i = 0; i < RANDOMS_NEEDED; i++) {
        int slotsOutput[3] = {};
        rando = rand();
        int randoInRange = rando % (rando_max + 1);
        cout << "|  " << randoInRange << "  |";
        slotsOutput[i] = randoInRange;
        Sleep(500);
        cout << slotsOutput[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for` loop, you are [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) your pre-declared variable `slotsOutPut`.

```cpp
int slotsOutput[3] = {}; // Declares here

...

for (int i = 0; i < RANDOMS_NEEDED; i++) {
        int slotsOutput[3] = {}; // Declared again, which shadows above slotsOutPut
```

What you were doing is, briefly.

```cpp
int asdf = 3; // asdf is 3 here
{
    int asdf = 4; // asdf is 4 here, but it's different asdf to above one.
    cout << asdf; // prints 4
} // local variable asdf is gone with the end of the scope.
cout << asdf; // prints 3
```

It seems you have to remove the line `int slotsOutput[3] = {};` in `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I "save" the array values so they dont reset after exiting the loop?

You need to remove the code that reset the array inside the loop - it should already be done outside the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < RANDOMS_NEEDED; i++) {
    int slotsOutput[3] = {};  //<-- remove
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop, you declare a new array slotsOutput with the same name as the variable outside the loop.  The action inside the loop only affects this second array, which hides the first array by having the same name.  When the loop exits, the second array disappears and you have access to the first one, that is unchanged.

Your compiler should warn about this if you have the proper warning level enabled.